# git commit --fixup hash does nothing

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a commit I want to fixup. what am I doing wrong?

```
git commit --fixup bdf55a7c12996e3af853c27ca4ff6c670e826c5e
On branch foo
nothing to commit, working tree clean
git --version
git version 2.31.0
```

Comment: Is what the output says true?...are there no pending changes in your tree to commit?  Do a "git status" and add the result to your question.

Comment: If you _already committed_ your new commit (no changes are still staged), `git commit --fixup` isn't expected to do anything. You want `git rebase -i`.

Comment: @CryptoFool yes the output is true

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't understand the need for fixup if you haven't committed the commit.  If you haven't made a commit, there's no commit message that could be used to prime the fixup commit

Comment: @Joshua, huh? The whole idea of a fixup is that you're changing content and _not_ changing the message. Hence, `--fixup=that-other-commit` creates a dummy message that `git rebase --autosquash` recognizes as a "this commit I'm now creating should be treated as a fixup to that-other-commit, not a real commit with its own message".

Comment: @Joshua, ...so, if you _already_ committed the code you want to apply as a fixup, it's too late to give it that dummy message; you can just go straight to `git rebase -i`, change the operation type to `fixup` by hand in your editor, and move the line to be directly below the line for `that-other-commit` (which are the two things that `commit --fixup` would make `rebase --autosquash` do automatically on your behalf).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't realize it wasn't meant for commit messages.  I still don't think I understand how to use the fixup tool correctly from your description

Comment: Honestly, the `commit --fixup` flag doesn't do anything you can't accomplish just as well without it. Make sure you understand how the `fixup` marker works in `git rebase -i`, and if you're comfortable with that, you can do anything that `--fixup` would do for you without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66765470/git-commit-fixup-hash-does-nothing#comment118028516_66765470):

> I didn't realize it wasn't meant for commit messages.

There is currently no `git commit` option that *is* meant for that.<sup>1</sup>  Instead, you need to run `git rebase -i` (as you would normally anyway) and then change the `pick` line for that particular commit to a `reword` line.

> I still don't think I understand how to use the fixup tool correctly ...

The thing to understand here is that `git commit --fixup` and `git commit --squash` are relatively late inventions.  What comes *first* is `git rebase --interactive`.  (There is a whole lot more background to understand as well, but let's just assume that you understand exactly what `git rebase` does and how it does it, via repeaeted cherry-picking.  If you don't, that's a separate question—which is already asked and answered here on StackOverflow, so search for those Q&As.)

Now, since rebase is essentially a series of cherry-pick operations, we observe that a mechanical, automatic, copy-every-commit-as-is rebase is kind of boring.  We add some *excitement!!! (insert blockbuster movie explosions and loud noises here)* by turning the series of cherry-picks into a block of commands:

```
pick a123456   subject line from that commit
pick b789abc   another commit subject line
pick cef0123   ... etc ...
pick d456789   and so on
```

Then, having made up this "instruction sheet", we give you—the user—the opportunity to *edit* this instruction sheet.

You can change the *order* of the `pick` lines, for instance.  This means that instead of the cherry-picks being done in the original order, they're done in the new order you choose.  So you can re-shuffle the *order* of commits.  If you got one commit wrong, and used a later commit to fix it up somehow, you can put the wrong-and-fixup commits next to each other!

So far, that's not a whole lot of help.  You change:

```
pick a123456   subject line from that commit
pick b789abc   another commit subject line
pick cef0123   ... etc ...
pick d456789   and so on
pick eabcdef   whoops
```

into:

```
pick a123456   subject line from that commit
pick b789abc   another commit subject line
pick eabcdef   whoops
pick cef0123   ... etc ...
pick d456789   and so on
```

where the "whoops" commit repairs a mistake you made in commit `b789abc`.  OK, so if you run *these* instructions, the rebased result is that the mistake-commit and the fixing-commit are now *adjacent*, rather than separated by (the copies of) commits `cef0123` followed by `d456789`.

But now we add *more options*.  Rather than just `pick`, for instance, we add the option `squash`.  This tells Git that instead of just cherry-picking commit `eabcdef`—the one that fixes the earlier commit—it should turn the *two* commits into a *single combined commit*.  It should also take the commit *log messages* from the two commits, and put them into a single temporary file and use that temporary file as the commit message ... **after** giving you a chance to *edit* that file!

So now you can edit the two commit messages down into a single commit message, for the combine commit that results from squashing the defective commit together with its repair commit!  That's the original idea here.

---

<sup>1</sup>There is an in-progress effort to add a new commit option just for this.

---

#### Let's pause a moment and take stock

So, with an interactive rebase that knows only two options—`pick` and `squash`—we get the following abilities:

- We can *re-order* commits, to put closely correlated commits next to each other.
- We can *combine* commits.  When we do we're thrown into our editor to make up the correct commit message for the combined commit.

Now that we can do this much, let's think about what other things we might want to be able to do:

- If there's a typo in some commit message, it would be nice to be able to fix it.

  So, to our two existing options—`pick` and `squash`—let's add a `reword` option.  This will cherry-pick the commit, but will also throw us into our editor to let us *change the commit message* first.
- If there's a goof-up in a commit, but we have a fix for it *and we don't need to fix its commit message*, it would be nice to be able to put the fixup commit right after the broken commit.  We can already do that by moving it around and using `squash`.  But this throws us into our editor.  It would be nicer to just *keep* the commit *message* from the broken commit, while squashing the two commits.

  So, to our existing options, let's add a `fixup` option.  This will do the squashing, just like `squash` does, but *won't* put us into our editor.  It will *throw away* the fixup commit's *message* entirely, keeping the message from the slightly broken commit while squashing in the fixup.

These give us some of the commands that interactive rebase can do.  We get a few more (like `edit`, which picks the commit but then stops, as if there were a conflict) before we stop and declare that our interactive rebase feature is nifty and should be part of Git and get it into a Git release.  Then it sits there in Git for some years.

Now that some years have gone by, we say: *Hey, it might be nice if we could have `git commit` **annotate** a commit, at the time we make it, to say that it's a squash or fixup commit that `git rebase --interactive` should turn into a `squash` or `rebase` **automatically**.*  This is the situation you've walked into.  You came in late in the movie, and aren't aware of all this background, but now you've read some spoilers to explain the first part of the movie and how we got here.

This explains why you get the error you do: a `--fixup` commit is supposed to be fixing a goof in the *committed files*.  It's not for fixing up the *commit message*.  There is no way to do that with `git commit` just yet.  Instead, you have to run the `git rebase -i` yourself, and change the `pick` line to a `reword` line.

Comment: your sections on what fixup actually does is what ultimately answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you think that `git commit --fixup` changes an existing commit. It doesn't. [`git commit --fixup`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---fixupltcommitgt) and `git commit --squash` are parts of history rewriting but they're only part of the solution.

`git commit --fixup` doesn't change the commit you point it to. It creates a new commit at the head of the current branch with the subject constructed from the given commit with the word `fixup!`  prepended. The commit is a usual commit that contains the current changes so use `git add` or `git commit -a --fixup` to add and commit changes.

After that run [`git rebase --interactive --autosquash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---autosquash) — this is the main command that does fixup/squash. The command reorders the commits and presents you with the list of commits to fixup/squash. Verify the list and exit your editor. `git rebase` will run fixing up or squashing commits.

See how everything can be combined in one clever alias: https://blog.filippo.io/git-fixup-amending-an-older-commit/

```
[alias]
        fixup = "!f() { TARGET=$(git rev-parse "$1"); git commit --fixup=$TARGET ${@:2} && EDITOR=true git rebase -i --autostash --autosquash $TARGET^; }; f"
```

To use it:

```
git fixup bdf55a7c12996e3af853c27ca4ff6c670e826c5e
```

Comment: I must not understand, if I give git commit --fixup a hash, shouldn't it use that hash to rebase and make a new commit? or at least create a new commit with the same contents and the fixme! commit message?

Comment: @Joshua, the hash you give it is the hash that `rebase --autosquash` will place _the new commit you're now creating_ (a concept that only makes sense when you have staged, uncommitted changes) directly on top of. So if you previously committed "bugfix foo" and spot a typo, you can `git add` a fix for that typo, then `git commit --fixup=bugfix-foo-hash` to make `git rebase -i --autosquash` know it should treat your typo fix as something to amend to the bugfix-foo-hash commit.

Comment: @Joshua Nop, when you give `git commit --fixup` a hash the hash is used to construct a new commits' message subject from the subject of the message at the given commit. And nothing more.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So how do I get the new commit created so that I can edit the message?

Comment: @Joshua, ...if it's going to exist in history with its own message (more than just temporarily / until you rebase), it's not a fixup. The _whole point_ of fixups is that they're going to be destroyed by being squashed into an existing commit while keeping that existing commit's message unchanged (that's the difference between a fixup and a regular squash; with a regular squash the user is given the chance to merge the two commit messages, whereas with a fixups the commit being "fixed up" by squashing in additional changes keeps its original message).

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), "[`git commit --fixup=<commit>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89519f662c9e2b1c406fa72ba7923fcf5c028e89/Documentation/git-commit.txt#L89-L126)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---fixupltcommitgt))</sup>, has changed.

It was to tweak the changes made to the contents while keeping the original log message intact, but it now has learned "`--fixup=(amend|reword):<commit>`", that can be used to tweak both the message and the contents, and only the message, respectively.

See [commit 00ea64e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00ea64ed7a0ee5ef0901b1eeb5add6954925590f), [commit 8bedae4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8bedae4599fafa8ae8b2885454db7c4bb7660aeb), [commit 3d1bda6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d1bda6b5bed6b29723178b1b417b3a5abe62565), [commit 3270ae8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3270ae82acdec3d25491427e0ecff43c014ac4d9), [commit 494d314](https://github.com/git/git/commit/494d314a0526a8bee9f8af7a6e6b74b66043c9fa), [commit 6e0e288](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e0e28877988f8b98eb1e5cf4d4c5d29cc0b7f77) (15 Mar 2021) by [Charvi Mendiratta (`charvi-077`)](https://github.com/charvi-077).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 89519f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89519f662c9e2b1c406fa72ba7923fcf5c028e89), 26 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/494d314a0526a8bee9f8af7a6e6b74b66043c9fa): add amend suboption to --fixup to create amend! commit
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Charvi Mendiratta</sup>

> [`git commit --fixup=amend:<commit>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89519f662c9e2b1c406fa72ba7923fcf5c028e89/Documentation/git-commit.txt#L89-L126)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---fixupltcommitgt))</sup> will create an "`amend!`" commit.
> The resulting commit message subject will be "`amend! ...`" where "`...`" is the subject line of `<commit>` and the initial message body will be `<commit>`'s message.
>
> The "`amend!`" commit when rebased with `--autosquash` will fixup the contents and replace the commit message of `<commit>` with the "amend!" commit's message body.
>
> In order to prevent rebase from creating commits with an empty message we refuse to create an "`amend!`" commit if commit message body is empty.

In details:

> ### [`doc/git-commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/00ea64ed7a0ee5ef0901b1eeb5add6954925590f): add documentation for `fixup=[amend|reword] options`
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Charvi Mendiratta</sup>

`git commit` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/00ea64ed7a0ee5ef0901b1eeb5add6954925590f/Documentation/git-commit.txt#L12):

> `[--dry-run] [(-c | -C | --squash) <commit> | --fixup [(amend|reword):]<commit>)]`

`git commit` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/00ea64ed7a0ee5ef0901b1eeb5add6954925590f/Documentation/git-commit.txt#L89-L126):

> ### `--fixup=[(amend|reword):]<commit>`
>
> Create a new commit which "fixes up" `<commit>` when applied with
> `git rebase --autosquash`.
>
> Plain `--fixup=<commit>` creates a
> "fixup!" commit which changes the content of `<commit>` but leaves
> its log message untouched.
>
> `--fixup=amend:<commit>` is similar but
> creates an "`amend!`" commit which also replaces the log message of
> `<commit>` with the log message of the "`amend!`" commit.
>
> `--fixup=reword:<commit>` creates an "`amend!`" commit which
> replaces the log message of `<commit>` with its own log message
> but makes no changes to the content of `<commit>`.
>
> The commit created by plain `--fixup=<commit>` has a subject
> composed of "`fixup!`" followed by the subject line from `<commit>`,
> and is recognized specially by `git rebase --autosquash`.
> The `-m` option may be used to supplement the log message of the created
> commit, but the additional commentary will be thrown away once the
> "`fixup!`" commit is squashed into `<commit>` by
> `git rebase --autosquash`.
>
> The commit created by `--fixup=amend:<commit>` is similar but its
> subject is instead prefixed with "`amend!`".
> The log message of `<commit>` is copied into the log message of the "`amend!`" commit and opened in an editor so it can be refined.
> When `git rebase --autosquash` squashes the "`amend!`" commit into `<commit>`, the
> log message of `<commit>` is replaced by the refined log message
> from the "`amend!`" commit.
>
> It is an error for the "`amend!`" commit's log message to be empty unless `--allow-empty-message` is
> specified.
>
> `--fixup=reword:<commit>` is shorthand for `--fixup=amend:<commit> --only`.
> It creates an "`amend!`" commit with only a log message
> (ignoring any changes staged in the index).
> When squashed by `git rebase --autosquash`, it replaces the log message of `<commit>` without making any other changes.
>
> Neither "`fixup!`" nor "`amend!`" commits change authorship of
> `<commit>` when applied by `git rebase --autosquash`.

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/00ea64ed7a0ee5ef0901b1eeb5add6954925590f/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L596-L606):

> When the commit log message begins with "`squash! ...`" or "`fixup! ...`"
> or "`amend! ...`", and there is already a commit in the todo list that
> matches the same `...`, automatically modify the todo list of
> `rebase -i`, so that the commit marked for squashing comes right after
> the commit to be modified, and change the action of the moved commit
> from `pick` to `squash` or `fixup` or `fixup -C` respectively.
>
> A commit
> matches the `...` if the commit subject matches, or if the `...` refers
> to the commit's hash.
>
> As a fall-back, partial matches of the commit
> subject work, too.
>
> The recommended way to create fixup/amend/squash
> commits is by using the `--fixup`, `--fixup=amend:` or `--fixup=reword:`
> and `--squash` options respectively of [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit).

---

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), "[`git commit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6e21f716f89d190017fa675738e9e7cc1a74680a/Documentation/git-commit.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit))</sup> `--fixup` now works with `--edit` again, after it was broken in v2.32.

See [commit 8ef6aad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ef6aad664715c16caf6e36a7f6b174a06574477) (14 Aug 2021) by [Joel Klinghed (`thejk`)](https://github.com/thejk).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6e21f71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e21f716f89d190017fa675738e9e7cc1a74680a), 03 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ef6aad664715c16caf6e36a7f6b174a06574477): restore --edit when combined with --fixup
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Joel Klinghed</sup>

> Recent changes to `--fixup`, adding amend suboption, caused the `--edit` flag to be ignored as `use_editor` was always set to zero.
>
> Restore `edit_flag` having higher priority than `fixup_message` when deciding the value of `use_editor` by moving the edit flag condition later in the method.